# crash dump show register value changed, but i can not find which instruction change it

Tags: c++, windows, stl, crash

I am currently analyzing a crash dump. The crash occurs in the stl string assign function. There is only one thread in process and the process is running in the VMware virtual machine(win2008 server r2).

Here's the context record:

```
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=000000013f2c96e0
rdx=000000013f344924 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=00000000002df498
rip=000000013f1f2705 rsp=00000000002df350 rbp=00000000002df489
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=000000013f1d0000 r10=000000013f344924
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
XXXXX!std::_WChar_traits::assign+0x2 [inlined in XXXXX!std::basic_string,std::allocator >::assign+0x55]:
000000013f1f2705 66890433        mov     word ptr [rbx+rsi],ax ds:0000000000000000=????
```

Here is the `mov` instruction context:

```
00000001`3f1f26ed 488d1c12        lea     rbx,[rdx+rdx]
00000001`3f1f26f1 48895110        mov     qword ptr [rcx+10h],rdx
00000001`3f1f26f5 4c8bc3          mov     r8,rbx
00000001`3f1f26f8 498bd1          mov     rdx,r9
00000001`3f1f26fb 488bce          mov     rcx,rsi
00000001`3f1f26fe e80d6f0d00      call    XXXXX!memcpy (00000001`3f2c9610)
00000001`3f1f2703 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00000001`3f1f2705 66890433        mov     word ptr [rbx+rsi],ax
```

I have checked the `memcpy` function, this function do not change `rsi` register value.

But the dump shows the `rsi` register value is zero when cpu execute `mov word ptr [rbx+rsi],ax` instruction.
How is this possible? Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you not able to single-step the program in a debugger?

Comment: Why do you think `rsi` was not zero at the start of this sequence?  None of these instructions change its value.  This looks like it is setting a 16 bit `wstring` from a `NULL` `wchar_t` pointer, with `rsi` holding that pointer.

Comment: The origin cpp code like this: `_wszString = L""`; I think this cpp code can not crash. But the dump shows program crash in this code.